# How to exit from `RunLoop`

Tags: swift, multithreading, foundation, nsrunloop, cfrunloop

I'm subclassing `InputStream` from iOS Foundation SDK for my needs. I need to implement functionality that worker thread can sleep until data appear in the stream. The test I'm using to cover the functionality is below:

```swift
    func testStreamWithRunLoop() {
        let inputStream = BLEInputStream() // custom input stream subclass
        inputStream.delegate = self
        let len = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
        let randomData = randData(length: len) // random data generation
        
        let tenSeconds = Double(10)
        let oneSecond = TimeInterval(1)
        runOnBackgroundQueueAfter(oneSecond) {
            inputStream.accept(randomData) // input stream receives the data
        }
        let dateInFuture = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: tenSeconds) // time in 10 sec
        inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default) // 
        RunLoop.current.run(until: dateInFuture) // wait for data appear in input stream
        XCTAssertTrue(dateInFuture.timeIntervalSinceNow > 0, "Timeout. RunLoop didn't exit in 1 sec. ")
    }
```

Here the overriden methods of `InputStream`

```swift
    public override func schedule(in aRunLoop: RunLoop, forMode mode: RunLoop.Mode) {
        self.runLoop = aRunLoop // save RunLoop object
        var context = CFRunLoopSourceContext() // make context
        self.runLoopSource = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(nil, 0, &context) // make source
        let cfloopMode: CFRunLoopMode = CFRunLoopMode(mode as CFString) 
        CFRunLoopAddSource(aRunLoop.getCFRunLoop(), self.runLoopSource!, cfloopMode)
    }

public func accept(_ data: Data) { 
        guard data.count > 0 else { return }
        
        self.data += data
        delegate?.stream?(self, handle: .hasBytesAvailable)
        
        if let runLoopSource {
            CFRunLoopSourceSignal(runLoopSource)
        }
        if let runLoop {
            CFRunLoopWakeUp(runLoop.getCFRunLoop())
        }
    }
```

But calling `CFRunLoopSourceSignal(runLoopSource)` and `CFRunLoopWakeUp(runLoop.getCFRunLoop())` not get exit from runLoop.

[image: Test is failing]
Does anybody know where I'm mistaking ?

Thanks all!

PS: [Here the Xcode project on GitHub](https://github.com/iharkatkavets/ble-streams.swift)

Comment: Is the first code supposed to be a unit test? That is not how you wait for something to happen.

Comment: Also it is almost never right to sleep a thread. I would drop the whole run loop approach if I were you.

Comment: But this is the way how Apple suggest to work with sockets. What is your approach @matt ?

Comment: Well, I agree that a runloop is probably the wrong pattern, the historical way to exit the runloop is to spin on it yourself. See `run()` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1412430-run).

Comment: Spinning on a runloop is an anti-pattern nowadays. And when we did it before, we would use it to spin on a background thread (e.g., what we used to have to do run `NSURLConnection` on a background thread), not the current thread. But we have modern asynchronous patterns now. E.g., `URLSession` for network requests; [Network framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/715/) for sockets; [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) for BLE.

Comment: Any long term operation is only performing on side thread, it's clear. Please have a look my explanation in the answer

Comment: Have you considered using the existing non-blocking approaches to I/O? There are lots of well established strategies to wait on work (Async/await, dispatch sources, closure callbacks, etc.) without actually needing to spin a thread, background or not.

Comment: I will integrate this code to another part of the complex library which expects a stream for communication with end point device. @Alexander

Comment: I see that users votes against the question and attempting, should I remove my answer then...  ?

Comment: I upvoted, because it’s interesting, but I have to say that I really don’t understand desire to block a thread where so many more modern, sensible approaches exist

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out some issues with my code.

First of all I need to remove CFRunLoopSource object from run loop **`CFRunLoopRemoveSource()`**. In according with documentation if RunLoop has no input sources then it exits immediately.

```swift
    public func accept(_ data: Data) {
        guard data.count > 0 else { return }
        
        self.data += data
        delegate?.stream?(self, handle: .hasBytesAvailable)
        
        if let runLoopSource, let runLoop, let runLoopMode {
            CFRunLoopRemoveSource(runLoop.getCFRunLoop(), runLoopSource, runLoopMode)
        }
        if let runLoop {
            CFRunLoopWakeUp(runLoop.getCFRunLoop())
        }
    }
```

Second issue is related that I used XCTest environment and it's RunLoop didn't exit for some reasons (Ask the community for help).

I used real application environment and created Thread subclass to check my implementation. The thread by default has run loop without any input sources attached to it. I added input stream to it. And using main thread emulated that stream received data.

Here the Custom Thread implement that runs and sleep until it receive signal from BLEInputStream

```swift
class StreamThread: Thread, StreamDelegate {
    let stream: BLEInputStream
    
    init(stream: BLEInputStream) {
        self.stream = stream
    }
    
    override func main() {
        stream.delegate = self
        stream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        print("start()")
        let tenSeconds = Double(10)
        let dateInFuture = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: tenSeconds)
        RunLoop.current.run(until: dateInFuture)
        print("after 10 seconds")
    }
    
    override func start() {
        super.start()
    }
    
    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        if eventCode == .errorOccurred {
            print("eventCode == .errorOccurred")
        }
        else if eventCode == .hasBytesAvailable {
            print("eventCode == .hasBytesAvailable")
        }
    }
}
```

Here the some UIViewController methods which runs from main thread

```swift
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let baseDate = Date.now
        let thread = StreamThread(stream: stream, baseDate: baseDate)
        thread.start()
        print("main thread pauses at \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(baseDate))")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2) 
        print("stream accepts Data \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(baseDate))")
        stream.accept(Data([1,2,3]))
    }
```

Here the result:
[image]

Everything works as expected - the thread sleeps until input stream receive data. No processor resources consuming.

Although it's allowed to subclass InputStream, there is no good explanation in the documentation how to correctly implement custom InputStream

Answer (score 0):

1. In Apple's runtime, NSMainThread and MainRunLoop is very special object.
   MainRunLoop does `shallow sleep` rather than `deep sleep` like
   normal RunLoop. Apple's frameworks likely to dispatch events to
   MainRunLoop.

which means....

- MainRunLoop awakes automatically with CFRunLoopPerform and CFRunLoopSource0 signal
- OS and Frameworks likely to attach external sources and observer

2. Subclassing `OutputStream` and `InputStream` is not recommended. They are toll-free-bridged to `CFWriteStream` and `CFReadStream`, and Stream API are heavily depends on CFStream API

[CFReadStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfreadstream-ri6), [CFWriteStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfwritestream-rc8)

Consider using `CFReadStreamSetDispatchQueue(_:_:)` and `CFWriteStreamSetDispatchQueue(_:_:)` rather then `RunLoop` which is much easier.

```
extension InputStream {
    
    final var targetQueue:DispatchQueue? {
        get { CFReadStreamCopyDispatchQueue(self) }
        set { CFReadStreamSetDispatchQueue(self, newValue) }
    }
    
}

extension OutputStream {
    
    final var targetQueue:DispatchQueue? {
        get { CFWriteStreamCopyDispatchQueue(self) }
        set { CFWriteStreamSetDispatchQueue(self, newValue) }
    }
    
}
```